# How is starting and ending row number of a Range obtained?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, vba

Given a user-selected Range, what is the simplest way to determine the starting row number, and ending row number?

Range.Address returns a string containing any number of possible formats.  There has to be something simpler.

Desired:

```
Dim oRange As Range
Dim startRow As Integer
Dim endRow As Integer

oRange = Range("A1:X50")
startRow = oRange.Address.StartRow
endRow = oRange.Address.EndRow
```

of course, those properties do not exist.
I want to do the same to return column letters.

Comment: Don't forget that you can have multiple ranges selected very easily by the user.

Comment: True, but I would not allow a sort if more than one range was selected. Just as if multiple ranges are selected in Excel, and you click the Sort button, Excel throws an error. Something like, if necessary:

If oRange.Areas.Count > 1 Then MsgBox "Sort cannot be applied to multiple selected areas." End If

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
Dim oRange As Range
Dim startRow As Integer
Dim endRow As Integer

With Selection
    startRow = .Rows(1).Row
    endRow = .Rows(Selection.Rows.Count).Row
End With
```

Comment: Dude!  Thanks  Sorry I cannot +1 you yet.